# What's the meaning of "extensive series of"?

Tags: meaning

> Over the past several years we have offered an extensive series of short courses on the mathematics of biological complexity.
>
> This extensive series of pools sits in a forest at the foot of a line of Andean mountains.

I think the meaning of "extensive series of" is similar to "many", "a lot of". Is this correct?

Comment: What does "extensive" mean?  What is a "series".  Look them up in a dictionary .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Over the past several years we have offered an extensive series of
>   short courses on the mathematics of biological complexity.

**"extensive series of short courses"** here means **" a large number of short courses offered one after another"**. For example, once you finish the first course, you can take the second one with a higher level.

> This extensive series of pools sits in a forest at the foot of a line
>   of Andean mountains.

In this sentence, **"extensive series of pools"** means **" a large number of pools which are near each other"**. There are many pools next to each other and once you walk past one pool, you will see another one.

There is more information from the word "series", so it isn't exactly the same as "many" or "a lot of".